# Check the number of links that have been opened

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Suppose that i have a 100 links. Out of this 3 links have been opened ( the color would change ). How do i find which are the links that have been opened using selenium...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
JB.

Comment: Are u opening the links using selenium or manually?

Comment: Isn't this just a simple counter? Nothing to do with Selenium

Comment: Hemasundar - Its using selenium.

Comment: Arran - It has to be done using Selenium..Java Scripting.

Comment: Increment a counter or add the link to any collection everytime Selenium opens it.

Comment: The question is unclear! Are you asking: "How many links have been clicked in Selenium in the current session?" Or are you asking: "How many links are visited and stored in the local cache?"

Comment: Sorry. In a web Page 'there are 100 links and out of them some are read. How do i find the links that are read"

Comment: Links that have been previously visited is a function of the browser; further, there are certain browsers on the market, which do not offer this functionality. Since this is not a function of the DOM, it is impossible to test for using Selenium. You would need to parse the browser cache database for your particular browser.

Comment: @SiKing: It should be possible with selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS there is a method to style the visited links.

```
a:visited { }
```

So probably what you could do is to use the css selector to get those links.

Assuming you are using Java,

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a:visisted"));
```

The above code will give all the visited links in that session.

PS: This code is not tested as I am not in the position to try it.